# Practical size of Python Queue with infinite size

Tags: python, multithreading

When a Python queue is initialized with maxsize <= 0, its size is infinite:

> class Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
>
> Constructor for a FIFO queue. maxsize is an integer that sets the 
>   upperbound limit on the number of items that can be placed in the
>   queue. If maxsize is less than or equal to zero,
>   the queue size is infinite.

I am wondering what the practical limitation of the queue size is.

Background: I want to write an application that fetches data from a measuring device at a sample rate of -say- 2 kHz and put all data into a queue. On the other side there is a GUI periodically -say once a second- retrieving all data from the queue and updating a plot window. So my question is if this is a safe approach.

Comment: size will be based on your ram's size. If your data exceed your ram's size you will go out of memory.

Comment: So with 8 GB of RAM, of which 4 GB are free, I could simply consume these 4 GB with a huge queue of data? That should be enough...